# Angular : Downloading and unzipping a .zip file without writing to disk with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angular, blob, arraybuffer

My API returning application/octet-stream response which I am able to download in zip format. But I want to extract the zip into an actual file before downloading.

```
fetch('./api'). // its returnType: arraybuffer  
.then((result) => {
 const blob = new Blob([result.body], { type: "application/octet-stream" }); // converting to blob
  //--------
  // Here Before downloading the file I want to extract and download the actual file
  //--------
 saveAs(blob, fileName); // file-saver lib using to download
});
```

Comment: What's the point of answering you if you're going to delete your answer and ask again later on ? As said previously, use a library to do that.

Comment: @temp_user That zip.js is not having an MIT license also its Unpacked Size is 7.43 MB. So I can't use it as it will impact app performance.

Comment: That was one example, find another library suiting your needs ...

Comment: Have you solved it?